# Como ejecutar 2 funciones a través de Promesas nodejs , pero la respuesta de primera función no interviene en la segunda son independientes?

Tags: nodejs, express

Explico:

Tengo dos funciones la primera descarga un archivo y la segunda invoca un script de python, la cuestión es que cuando termine de descargar el archivo se llame al script y no me funciona.

Ejemplo:

```
    const upLoad = (req, res) =>{
        const image = uploadImage(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                err.message = 'The file is so heavy for my service';
                return res.send(err);
            }
            console.log(req.file);
        })
       .then(() => {
         const callPython = callScript();
    }
```

```
    const upLoad = async(req, res) =>{
        const image = await uploadImage(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                err.message = 'messageError';
                return res.send(err);
            }
            console.log(req.file);
        });
      
         const callPython = await callScript();
    }
```

No me funciona ninguna vía es decir no se ejecuta nunca la segunda función esto es un ejemplo pero básicamente por ahí viene la mano

Comment: Saludos. Prueba (espero te sirva); conforme al primer código que pusiste antes del `.then(...)` coloca `.ToPromise()` (sin nada dentro); así mismo debes verificar si es `ToPromise` o `Promise` lo que debes invocar.

Comment: ..})
    .ToPromise().then(() => {...  A esto te refieres ? lo probé así y sigue sin ejecutar la segunda función pero gracias tal ves por ahí esta la solución

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Quita el  `const image = ` y el `const callPython = ` que sea como instrucción directa; desde luego asumo que ` callScript();`si existe y esta en el alcance del contexto donde lo invocas.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta . al quitar las constantes funciono .. aunque también lo solucione de esta forma : ......async (req, res) => {
    await uploadImage(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            err.message = 'The file is so heavy for my service';
            return res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(req.file);
    })
     await callScript();.... gracias